# SQL Server SMSS Sorting Single Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

Hello I just wanted to make sure if I was doing this correctly. I have a students table with the columns StudentID, StudentLastName, StudentFirstName, DateOfBirth, GPA, Classification, BalanceDue, StudentMentorID .
For the query I only wanted it to return Classification, StudentID, StudentLastName, and GPA above a 3.25.

[image: Students Table]

The results should be sorted in descending order by Classification, and then by StudentLastName in ascending order.

```
SELECT Classification, StudentID, StudentLastName, GPA 
FROM Students
WHERE GPA >= 3.25
ORDER BY StudentLastName ASC, Classification DESC
```

[image: Ascending Order and Descending Order]

Comment: Your `order by` keys are in the wrong order.

Comment: Would that be the correct way its written and how the results are sorted?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could run it and see for yourself

Comment: It looks like your image is correct, but the code in this post is not.